# Bootstrap-select - selectpicker class dropdown not showing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The code I am working on uses JQuery to alow user to click a button which generates a row containing some form objects.
I want one of those objects to be a searchable dropdown, using [Bootstrap-Select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/).

Row is generated just fine, but no matter what I do, dropdown is not showing when selectpicker is set in:

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control">
```

Note that when I remove "selectpicker" from the class, dropdown shows just fine, but of course it is just a standard bootstrap one, not searchable.

Please see code below, I also created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gvwnqh2k/)

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col">
    <button type="button" value="Add a field" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add row</button>
    <br><br><br>
        <div id="sortable">
          <!-- Filled by JS -->
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    

<!-- Make form sortable using drag and drop -->
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>

<!-- Create form -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    
 
    // Add row functionality
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var exer_ids = ["1", "2", "3"];
        var exer_desc_pls = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"];
        var intId = $("#sortable div").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"form-row\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        var name = $("<div class=\"form-group col-md-4\"/>");
        var options = "<select class=\"selectpicker form-control\" data-live-search=\"true\"><option selected disabled>Pick option...</option>";
               
        var i;
        for (i=0; i < exer_ids.length; i++) {
            options += "<option data-tokens=\"" + exer_ids[i] + "\">" + exer_desc_pls[i] + "</option>";
        };
        
        options += "</select>";
        
        var url = $("<div class=\"form-group col-md-4\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"url\" placeholder=\"Paste here the URL of the Image\"class=\"form-control\"></div>");
        var removeButton = $("<div class=\"form-group col-md-1\"><button type=\"button\"class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\">Usuń</button></div>");      


        name.append(options);
        fieldWrapper.append(name);
        fieldWrapper.append(url);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        console.log(exer_ids.length);
        console.log(exer_ids);
        console.log(exer_desc_pls);

        $("#sortable").append(fieldWrapper);

        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the selectpicker after you create it.

I updated [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48un7cdg/) (See line #78)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    
 
    // Add row functionality
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var exer_ids = ["1", "2", "3"];
        var exer_desc_pls = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"];
        var intId = $("#sortable div").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"form-row\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        var name = $("<div class=\"form-group col-md-4\"/>");
        var options = "<select class=\"selectpicker form-control\" data-live-search=\"true\"><option selected disabled>Pick option...</option>";
               
        var i;
        for (i=0; i < exer_ids.length; i++) {
            options += "<option data-tokens=\"" + exer_ids[i] + "\">" + exer_desc_pls[i] + "</option>";
        };
        
        options += "</select>";
        
        var url = $("<div class=\"form-group col-md-4\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"url\" placeholder=\"Paste here the URL of the Image\"class=\"form-control\"></div>");
        var removeButton = $("<div class=\"form-group col-md-1\"><button type=\"button\"class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\">Usuń</button></div>");      


        name.append(options);
        fieldWrapper.append(name);
        fieldWrapper.append(url);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);

        $("#sortable").append(fieldWrapper);

        // At this point, the select tag and options ARE in your DOM
        // just not visible because Bootstrap is hiding them with CSS (or something)
        // So you need to have the JQuery step in to handle the visibility
        $('select').selectpicker();

        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: that worked like a charm. Thank you for the solution and the explanation.